# Is Access database independent of MS Access application?

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, portability

I use a .NET language to code an application to access MS Access database. I would ask if it is possible to use my application and its database on a PC that doesn't have MS Access installed on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often misquoted and misunderstood. The advice here is also correct.

So the so called JET database engine has been a part of windows and pre-installed as a default installed component for more than 10 years. In fact it was default on windows 98SE. This means that a fresh new out of the box windows machine could with no installed software using something like windows scripting could open up these Access files.

So you could from VB.net, c# etc. open up these files without any additional installed components.

However keep in mind that since office 2007, if you use the new accDB format files as opposed to mdb, then you WILL have to install a newer version of the JET engine. This newer version of the engine is compatible with older mdb files, but is required for opening access 2007 and beyond format databases. (accDB/accDE).

There's also a connection ability in this new engine to open up SharePoint tables or even connect to office 365 publish Access databases (and you can use SQl against those office 365 tables).

So in all cases, you never did need to install the Access application itself on the computer, however you do need a version of the database engine.

As noted for a very long time in the past, this database is and continues to be installed on windows by default.

However as noted, for newer format databases with multi value support, SharePoint support, database triggers and store procedures, and also that of 64 bit edition of this database engine? Then you will have to download and install a newer version of JET Which as noted is now called ACE.

Keep in mind that while to the newer version of the data engine has table triggers and store procedures (that will run when you modify data from .net), I do believe that you need ms-access to edit + create the new store procedures and you cannot create or edit the table triggers and store procedures using the ACE object model.

However, once table triggers and store procedures have been created, then once again you do NOT need Access installed on the computer for these table level triggers and procedures to run.

Comment: Yes, and also remember that the (old) Jet Engine runs only in 32-bit mode. So don't forget to set x86 as the target platform in the build options of your startup project. Otherwise it won't work on 64-bit machines.

Comment: A much more complete answer than mine was!  Great answer!

Comment: As noted, another issue is that there is a 64 bit version of ACE available for download and install. This 64 bit data engine provides 64 bit ODBC drivers and also allows 64 bit processes to open and read the new accDB. You can also use this 64 bit version of the data engine to read + open older legacy mdb files and do so with 64 bit code/processes. So one is not limited to using the older 32 bit version of JET, you can now use 64 bit in-process code to open such database files.

Answer (score 0):

Create Virtual Machine of the MS Windows and test it there. Yes it's possible.